# How to overwrite last line in Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView to which I am adding text by calling append().
In some circumstances I would rather overwrite the last line rather than add another line.
How to do this?

Comment: How do you define a 'line' in your `TextView`? There are a number of things to consider with `TextView`s. They are a container for text which can wrap and stretch based on a number of factors such as screen size, font size, pixel density, other views on the page etc. If you are appending lines to text view with a `\n` break, you could search for the latest break and substring it. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: show us the pattern of text in textview

Comment: The line delimiter is \n.  For example:  line1\nline2\nline3\n  I want to overwrite line3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html 
you can use substring, getText and setText.